# Set window width in jsDom?

Tags: node.js, jsdom

Should be a simple question.  How do I set the width in a jsDom object?

```
    jsdom.env({
        url:'http://testdatalocation',
        scripts: ['http://code.jquery.com/jquery.js'],
        done: function(errors, tstWindow) {
            console.log(tstWindow.innerWidth);
};
}
});
```

I can't figure out how to get the "innerWidth" to be anything but 1024

Comment: Your last sentence implies you tried to do it but it did not work. What did you try?

Comment: A number of things.  I tried tstWindow.resizeTo(#) tstWindow.resizeBy(#)  setting a "width" attribute, setting a innerWidth attribute, and some other things that I don't recall.

Comment: I suspect I am running into difficulty partly because of API changes, but also I seem not to have fully groked jsDom.  (Thanks for your help on my other question, Louis, this is a continuation of the same thing)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There isn't currently a formal option or API for doing so.

The values of `innerWidth` and similar properties are simply [set to literal values](https://github.com/tmpvar/jsdom/blob/1.0.3/lib/jsdom/browser/index.js#L256-L257):

```
DOMWindow.prototype = createFrom(dom || null, {
  // ...
  name: 'nodejs',
  innerWidth: 1024,
  innerHeight: 768,
  outerWidth: 1024,
  outerHeight: 768,
  // ...
});
```

Beyond test cases and documentation, [`outerWidth` isn't referenced elsewhere else in jsdom](https://github.com/tmpvar/jsdom/search?utf8=%E2%9C%93&q=innerWidth), so you could probably assign a new value within the [`created` event](https://www.npmjs.org/package/jsdom#-created-error-window-), updating `outerWidth` as well.

> *The primary use-case for `created` is to modify the window object (e.g. add new functions on built-in prototypes) before any scripts execute.*

```
created: function (errors, tstWindow) {
    tstWindow.outerWidth = tstWindow.innerWidth = 1440;
},
done: function(errors, tstWindow) {
    console.log(tstWindow.innerWidth);
}
```

Comment: Will this be passed on to any javascript on the page?

Comment: @SkipHuffman If moved to the `created` event, vs. `done` as I had it, yes. That event's intention is to allow modifying `window` before any scripts are run.

Answer (score 5):

The `resizeTo` and `resizeBy` methods are not implemented. You can see that by searching through the code base of jsdom:

```
$ grep -P 'resize(To|By)' `find . -type f`
./lib/jsdom/browser/index.js:    resizeBy: NOT_IMPLEMENTED(null, 'window.resizeBy'),
./lib/jsdom/browser/index.js:    resizeTo: NOT_IMPLEMENTED(null, 'window.resizeTo'),
```

If you just want to set the window size once and for all at initialization time, you could just set the `innerWidth` value to whatever you want. In a real browser, this is not the right way to do it, but in jsdom it would work.

However, if you have code that depends on `resizeTo` being present, you can add your own polyfill to the constructor that builds windows:

```
var jsdom = require("jsdom");

var document = jsdom.env({
    html: "<html></html>",
    done: function (error, w) {
        console.log(w.innerWidth, w.innerHeight);
        w.constructor.prototype.resizeTo = function (width, height) {
            this.innerWidth = this.outerWidth = width;
            this.innerHeight = this.outerHeight = height;
        };
        w.resizeTo(100, 200);
        console.log(w.innerWidth, w.innerHeight);
    }
});
```

This displays:

```
1024 768
100 200
```

The code above is for illustration purposes. I've not thought about all the ins and outs of writing a polyfill for `resizeTo`. `resizeBy` would be handled similarly but would add deltas to the size of the window.

Comment: Thanks, I am going to have to analyze that a bit.