# Jest / Enzyme - How to test at different viewports?

Tags: javascript, jestjs, enzyme, viewport, jsdom

I am trying to run a test on a component at a certain viewport width. I am doing the following, but this doesn't seem to change it:

```js
test('Component should do something at a certain viewport width.', () => {
    global.innerWidth = 2000;
    const component = mount(<SomeComponent />);
    // ...
});
```

I also found an article that explains how to do it using JSDom, but as Jest now ships with JSDom, I wondered if there was a native solution.

https://www.codementor.io/pkodmad/dom-testing-react-application-jest-k4ll4f8sd

Answer (score 50):

Background Information:

- `jsdom` [does not implement](https://github.com/jsdom/jsdom/blob/0cba358253fd5530af0685ac48c2535992464d06/lib/jsdom/browser/Window.js#L612-L613) `window.resizeBy()` or `window.resizeTo()`
- `jsdom` [defines the window innerWidth and innerHeight](https://github.com/jsdom/jsdom/blob/0cba358253fd5530af0685ac48c2535992464d06/lib/jsdom/browser/Window.js#L587-L588) to be 1024 x 768
- It is possible to simulate a window resize using `jsdom` by manually setting window.innerWidth and window.innerHeight and firing the `resize` event

Here is an example:

---

comp.js

```jsx
import * as React from 'react';

export default class Comp extends React.Component {
  constructor(...args) {
    super(...args);
    this.state = { width: 0, height: 0 }
  }
  updateDimensions = () => {
    this.setState({ width: window.innerWidth, height: window.innerHeight });
  }
  componentDidMount() {
    this.updateDimensions();
    window.addEventListener("resize", this.updateDimensions);
  }
  componentWillUnmount() {
    window.removeEventListener("resize", this.updateDimensions);
  }
  render() {
    return <div>{this.state.width} x {this.state.height}</div>;
  }
}
```

---

comp.test.js

```jsx
import * as React from 'react';
import { shallow } from 'enzyme';

import Comp from './comp';

const resizeWindow = (x, y) => {
  window.innerWidth = x;
  window.innerHeight = y;
  window.dispatchEvent(new Event('resize'));
}

describe('Comp', () => {
  it('should display the window size', () => {
    const component = shallow(<Comp />);

    expect(component.html()).toEqual('<div>1024 x 768</div>');

    resizeWindow(500, 300);
    expect(component.html()).toEqual('<div>500 x 300</div>');

    resizeWindow(2880, 1800);
    expect(component.html()).toEqual('<div>2880 x 1800</div>');
  });
});
```

Notes:

- As of `Enzyme` v3 `shallow` [calls React lifecycle methods like `componentDidMount()`](http://airbnb.io/enzyme/docs/api/shallow.html) so it can be used in place of `mount`
- This answer borrows heavily from the information [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19014495/10149510), [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26514724/10149510), [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26514718/10149510), and @JoeTidee's own answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46256392/10149510).

Comment: Is there a way to handle `Cannot assign to 'innerHeight' because it is a read-only property.`?

Comment: @kb_ When a test is running in `Jest` the `window` is the object provided by `jsdom` and its `innerHeight` property is a normal property.  I'm guessing you're getting this as a TypeScript error, in which case you may need to use a type assertion to tell TypeScript the property is not read-only.

Answer (score 9):

If you're using TypeScript it will complain that `window.innerWidth` / `innerHeight` are read-only. You can get around this by either redeclaring the property:

```js
Object.defineProperty(window, 'innerWidth', {writable: true, configurable: true, value: 105})
```

Or using the `Object.assign` method:

```js
window = Object.assign(window, { innerWidth: 105 });
```

Both are not extremely nice solutions, but they work.

Comment: but you can annotate with  //@ts-ignore

Answer (score 1):

The below test works for me. Source code is no longer marked as uncovered.

```js
it('resize event listener changes the state', () => {
  const wrapper = shallow(<Component />);
  const instance = wrapper.instance();

  instance.setState({
    mobileMode: true
  });

  global.innerWidth = 800;
  window.dispatchEvent(new Event('resize'));
  expect(instance.state.mobileMode).toBeFalsy();

  global.innerWidth = 600;
  window.dispatchEvent(new Event('resize'));
  expect(instance.state.mobileMode).toBeTruthy();
});
```

Resize listener inside my component:

```js
// ...
  resizeListener = () => {
      if (window.innerWidth < 768) {
        this.setState({
          mobileMode: true
        });
      } else {
        this.setState({
          mobileMode: false
        });
      }
    };
    window.addEventListener('resize', resizeListener);
// ...
```

Comment: It looks like there's some missing code for adding the `resizeListener`. One common way to use `window.addEventListener` is within `componentDidMount` in class-based React, or `useEffect` with Hooks.

Answer (score 0):

Having written helpers similar to the other answers in my tests a few times, I decided to create [`window-resizeto`](https://github.com/agilgur5/window-resizeto) as a *very* tiny library of reusable logic.

`window-resizeto` is a tiny polyfill for [`window.resizeTo`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/resizeTo) for test environments (as JSDOM [does not implement it](https://github.com/jsdom/jsdom/blob/a39e0ec4ce9a8806692d986a7ed0cd565ec7498a/lib/jsdom/browser/Window.js#L928)).

Per the [*Usage* section](https://github.com/agilgur5/window-resizeto#usage) of the README, you can add it to your `jest.config.js`:

```js
module.exports = {
  setupFilesAfterEnv: [
    // polyfill window.resizeTo
    'window-resizeto/polyfill'
  ]
}
```

and then use it in a spec file:

```js
window.resizeTo(500, 500) // window is now resized to 500x500
```

It's also written in TypeScript, so typings are provided out-of-the-box, and has 100% test coverage to ensure it keeps working correctly.