# Jest / Enzyme not behaving like app does with responsive changes

Tags: javascript, typescript, jestjs, enzyme

i have a footer that has a `<p>` element when it's greater than 576px but it's NOT rendered (display: none) if less than 576px.

Works perfect in browser.

Testing it with Jest / Enzyme is very difficult though.

I have a function:

```
const resizeWindow = (x, y) => {
  // @ts-ignore
  window.innerWidth = x;
  // @ts-ignore
  window.innerHeight = y;
  window.dispatchEvent(new Event('resize'));
};
```

This is then called in the test:

```
...test on desktop...

...test on mobile:-

it('should NOT show <p> tag if width < 576', () => {
   resizeWindow(300, 600);
   const numberOfPtags = mountedComponent.find('p').length;
   expect(numberOfPtags).toBe(0)
});
```

But it *always* comes through as `1`.

Even though the code would make it `display: none;` with those dimensions.

I found a way of logging out style and it had it as `display: block;` which is bizarre as I've only used `inline` and `none`.

I also logged out the window.innerWidth dimensions and they came out fine, so it obviously *is* changing them.

What am I missing here?

-- UPDATED --

screenshot of tests showing `global.innerWidth` instead of window, checking the width *has* definitely changed, and still the

tag remains. No idea what i'm doing wrong.

Thought it might be an async issue (eg waiting for the virtual window to resize, put a setTimeout in and the expect inside it... Jest totally skipped the setTimeout all together

[image: screeshot of code]

Comment: window.innerWidth and innerHeight are *read only*, you can't set them like that. However there is a hack, you can see here https://www.thetopsites.net/article/59307258.shtml or if you search stackoverflow, a question/answer duplicate answering yours.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Jest / Enzyme - How to test at different viewports?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46221210/jest-enzyme-how-to-test-at-different-viewports)

Comment: Have you tried [`toBeVisible()`](https://github.com/testing-library/jest-dom#tobevisible)?

Comment: @MaximeHelen using `toBeVisible()` or indeed anything from `@testing-library/jest-dom` creates a lot of `expect is not defined` or `cannot find declaration types for...` errors. I've tried adding it (as per Docs) to setup file, importing the method directly - both seem to fail.

Comment: @George I put TS Ignore onto those read-only warnings and they went away. In any case, i have switched to `global.innerWidth` now and it's the same. To be clear: the width *does* change, i can log that out and see it's reduced to 300. It's the *element* that doesnt. I'm expecting <p> to no longer be visible, but it remains.

Comment: `expect` is the built-in [`jest` object](https://jestjs.io/docs/en/expect) to match many things. You need it. I would double-check the environment, maybe this [github issue](https://github.com/testing-library/jest-dom/issues/122) could give you some good leads on how to fix this. Otherwise, I would make a new post describing your setup environment (package.json, config files...) or find a duplicate on that matter

Comment: Noticed in my Jest config there's a note re styling files. "anything style related is ignored and mapped to jest-transform-stub module". So i wonder if my scss (nested) mixins are just being ignored, would explain why test app isn't behaving like real app. 
@MaximeHelen

Comment: Just a sidenote: remember to use jest's `done()` when using `setTimeout` inside tests.

Comment: Turns out NONE of the styling was being incorporated into my unit tests, which explains by Media Queries & the Mixins applying them were not impacting the JS-DOM component. I simply don't have the time to spend days & weeks working out how to get Jest/Enzyme to respond to those - so i've begrudgingly settled for a manual test, code snapshot & the other click functionality of my footer icons.

I may return to this later though, if anyone comes across a simple NextJS/SCSS way to unit test media query led functionality.